# How to import the resw file from unity assets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, localization, resource-files

I want to use resw files in my app but i need to import these files from my unity assets folder , but i cant figure out a way to do that

. I have tried to put the resw file in unity resources folder and then reload all in my code but that also doesn't work.

Comment: do you have to use this or do you want to? What speaks against a simple `csv` file instead? Example header could be e.g. `ID, Comment, Language1, Language2, ...`. Then you could store it either in a Dictionary on the `ID` or make one Dictionary for each language etc .. depending on your needs